# Tex capacity exceeded compiling only 50 lines latex file (pdftex), seg. fault (lualatex)

Tags: errors, luatex, verbatim, breqn, memory

This is one of the strangest things I've seen in Latex (and I have seen many strange things). 50 lines of code, almost all of it is `verbatim`.

Any small change to the verbatim can cause the error to go away. it seems random. I managed to get it to 50 lines verbatim and still show the error. But if I make small change, remove 2-3 lines or delete an empty line, the error could go away or it might stay. it is random. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}%ext
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %DO NOT USE WIT LUALATEX, only with pdflatex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{breqn}   %do not use this with tex4ht.  added 4/2/16

\begin{document}
\section{How to implement Steepest descent for finding minumum of $f(x,y)$ ?}

\begin{verbatim}

    function nma_problem_2()
    close all;
    del      = 0.05;
    u1       = 0:del:20;
    u2       = -10:del:15;
    [u1,u2]  = meshgrid(u1,u2);

    plot(0,0);
    xlim([0 20]); ylim([-5 15]);
    hold on;
    [u(1),u(2)] = ginput(1);
    t=text(1.08*u(1),u(2),sprintf('[%2.1f,%2.1f]',u(1),u(2)));
    t.FontSize=8;
    t.Color='red';
    x = fminsearch(@objectiveFunc, u); %used to find the minumum in order to show
    %progress towards it
    hold on;
    plot(x(1),x(2),'*r')
    plot(u(1),u(2),'or')

    MAX_ITER = 50;
    REL_TOL  = 10^(-4);
    stepSize = -1; %optimal
    [p,levelSets] = steepestDescentPoints(u,MAX_ITER,REL_TOL,stepSize,...
    @objectiveFunc,@gradientFunc);
    [C,h]    = contour(u1,u2,z,levelSets); %,'ShowText','on');

    if length(p(:,1))>1
    for k=1:length(p)-1
    line([p(k,1),p(k+1,1)],[p(k,2),p(k+1,2)]); %draw line between each step
    drawnow;
    pause(.2);
    title(sprintf('starting from [%3.3f,%3.3f], f(u)=%3.3f,  step = %d',...
    u(1),u(2),norm(objectiveFunc(u)),k));
    end
    end
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Please make sure not to modify the code before seeing the error, as any small change to the `verbatim` code, could mask the error away! I also put the above source as [in this folder](http://12000.org/tmp/052016/)

Here is the error

```
pwd
/media/data/latex/standalone_2

pdflatex foo.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancybox/fancybox.sty
Style option: `fancybox' v1.4 <2010/05/15> (tvz)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/breqn.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/flexisym.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/cmbase.sym)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/mathstyle.sty))) (./foo.aux
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)
Overfull \hbox (75.69456pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 50--50
[]\T1/cmtt/m/n/10.95 x = fminsearch(@objectiveFunc, u); %used to find the minum
um in order to show[] 

Overfull \hbox (30.4276pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 50--50
[]\T1/cmtt/m/n/10.95 [p,levelSets] = steepestDescentPoints(u,MAX_ITER,REL_TOL,s
tepSize,...[] 

Overfull \hbox (41.74434pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 50--50
[]\T1/cmtt/m/n/10.95 line([p(k,1),p(k+1,1)],[p(k,2),p(k+1,2)]); %draw line betw
een each step[] 

Overfull \hbox (41.74434pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 50--50
[]\T1/cmtt/m/n/10.95 title(sprintf('starting from [%3.3f,%3.3f], f(u)=%3.3f,  s
tep = %d',...[] 

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=8000000].
,->\leavevmode \kern \z@ 
                         \char `\,
l.50 \end{verbatim}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on foo.log.
standalone_2>
```

This that will go the error to go away:

change the line `\section{How to implement Steepest descent for finding minumum of $f(x,y)$ ?}` to `\section{How to implement Steepest descent for finding minumum of f ?}`

also delete the empty line after `verbatim` i.e. change

```
\begin{verbatim}

    function nma_problem_2()
```

to

```
\begin{verbatim}
    function nma_problem_2()
```

also remove the `breqn` package will remove the error.

And many other little things like this. The error can go away by random. May be it is `breqn` fault again, I do not know.

question is: How to resolve this error? What is causing it?

TL 2015 on Linux. Error also shows on windows under miktex.

btw, **lualatex core dumps** on this file also

```
standalone_2>lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0.1 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5863) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/breqn.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/flexisym.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/cmbase.sym)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/mathstyle.sty))) (./foo.aux
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)
Overfull \hbox (75.69456pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--28
[][]\T1/cmtt/m/n/10.95 x = fminsearch(@objectiveFunc, u); %used to find the min
umum in order to show[] 

Overfull \hbox (30.4276pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 37--37
[][]\T1/cmtt/m/n/10.95 [p,levelSets] = steepestDescentPoints(u,MAX_ITER,REL_TOL
,stepSize,...[] 

Overfull \hbox (41.74434pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 43--43
[][]\T1/cmtt/m/n/10.95 line([p(k,1),p(k+1,1)],[p(k,2),p(k+1,2)]); %draw line be
tween each step[] 

Overfull \hbox (41.74434pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 46--46
[][]\T1/cmtt/m/n/10.95 title(sprintf('starting from [%3.3f,%3.3f], f(u)=%3.3f, 
 step = %d',...[] 

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [node memory size=385258750].
,->\leavevmode \kern \z@ 
                         \char `\,
l.49    end

Segmentation fault
```

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes are you joking or for real? one can't have a blank line in verbatim?  I had actually before used fancyverb. But I simplified  the example to use verbatim instead. I can put the fancyverb back if needed.?

Comment: Of course the issue is due to `breqn`.

Comment: I guess I was inadvertantly joking (another way of saying I was wrong) since a simpler `verbatim` text does not suffer this problem.  +1 for the conundrum.

Comment: @egreg I see a lot of questions on this site, the problems for which arise from `breqn`.  Is there an underlying message here?

Comment: I have to use `breqn` it is all over my code, but I also need to use `verbatim`. Why would `breqn` has anything to do with `verbatim`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It crashes for me in TL16 (but not in TL15). I will look into it and try to minimize it.

Comment: Three things appear to be needed: i) `breqn` must be loaded; ii) there must be a comma in math mode in the section heading and iii) the verbatim has to be long enough to break to the next page. (Edit: for the capacity problem, tested with `pdflatex`, TL15.)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer,@DavidCarlisle: we are seeing it now.

Comment: Fixed in experimental.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error is due to `breqn`, of course. Only one definition for an active character can be valid at a given time.

Since you have a math comma in the section title, this goes in the header and, with that long `verbatim`, it gets typeset when `verbatim` is active, which gives a different meaning to the active comma.

Here's a minimal example showing the issue.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{breqn}

\setlength{\textheight}{2cm} % to shorten the input

\begin{document}
\section{$f(x,y)$}

\begin{verbatim}
x
x
x
x
x
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Here's a fix to `\do@noligs`, which is responsible for defining a new meaning for active characters in `verbatim`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\def\do@noligs#1{%
  \catcode`#1\active
  \begingroup\lccode`\~`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup
  \ifdefined~%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter~\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\relax
      \expandafter\ifmmode
        ~% in math mode use the meaning given by breqn
      \else
        \leavevmode\kern\z@\char`#1\relax
      \fi
    }%
  \else
    \def~{\leavevmode\kern\z@\char`#1}%
  \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textheight}{2cm}

\begin{document}
\section{$f(x,y)$}

\begin{verbatim}
x
x
x
x
x
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

The main problem is the breqn math comma being written to the mark used in headings while verbatim is active. which gives a classic fragile command in moving argument cryptic error. `\hbox` hides this (a better fix allowing the comma to be used normally may be posted later)

The fact that luatex segfaults after the runaway argument is a separate lower level bug (or not a bug). The code uses arbitrary amounts of memory as it is in an infinite loop, so in classic tex it hits a hard limit but luatex just allocates more and more memory until it runs out of memory of your actual hardware.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}%ext
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %DO NOT USE WIT LUALATEX, only with pdflatex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{breqn}   %do not use this with tex4ht.  added 4/2/16



\begin{document}

\section{How to implement Steepest descent for finding minumum of  $f(x\hbox{,}y)$ ?}


\begin{verbatim}

    function nma_problem_2()
    close all;
    del      = 0.05;
    u1       = 0:del:20;
    u2       = -10:del:15;
    [u1,u2]  = meshgrid(u1,u2);

    plot(0,0);
    xlim([0 20]); ylim([-5 15]);
    hold on;
    [u(1),u(2)] = ginput(1);
    t=text(1.08*u(1),u(2),sprintf('[%2.1f,%2.1f]',u(1),u(2)));
    t.FontSize=8;
    t.Color='red';
    x = fminsearch(@objectiveFunc, u); %used to find the minumum in order to show
    %progress towards it
    hold on;
    plot(x(1),x(2),'*r')
    plot(u(1),u(2),'or')

    MAX_ITER = 50;
    REL_TOL  = 10^(-4);
    stepSize = -1; %optimal
    [p,levelSets] = steepestDescentPoints(u,MAX_ITER,REL_TOL,stepSize,...
    @objectiveFunc,@gradientFunc);
    [C,h]    = contour(u1,u2,z,levelSets); %,'ShowText','on');

    if length(p(:,1))>1
    for k=1:length(p)-1
    line([p(k,1),p(k+1,1)],[p(k,2),p(k+1,2)]); %draw line between each step
    drawnow;
    pause(.2);
    title(sprintf('starting from [%3.3f,%3.3f], f(u)=%3.3f,  step = %d',...
    u(1),u(2),norm(objectiveFunc(u)),k));
    end
    end
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @TorbjørnT. sorry that was a leftover from debugging (actually I saw your comment above after posting this you'd reached same conclusion i wouldn't have posted had I seen it:-)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. answer works now.  (no time to patch the headings to make comma safe just now)